# Mathematical meaning of Residual Sum of Squares

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, variance

I know what is [Residual Sum of Squares (RSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares). The problem is I don't understand why it works.

For example, you have a set of descreet values, and you want to describe them with linear, quadratic or any other function. To choose the best function you calculate the RSS (sum of variances) instead sum of deviances.

*Why to choose the most precise function you have to sum variances (instead of deviances)? How is that prooved?*

Comment: Well, you can use a different error function if you like.  People often do.  Least squares has some nice properties...easy to work with mathematically and there's the [Gauss Markov Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem) which tells us that doing it this way minimizes the variance of the estimate.  But other error functions may reduce (or increase) the effect of outliers, say, which is often desired.

Comment: For the linear regression model there are multiple reasons. First, is the Gauss Markov Theorem pointed above. Second, for the case of normally distributed errors, the OLS estimator coincides with the maximum likelihood estimator. Third, there is a simple closed-form formula available for the OLS estimator of a linear regression model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be specific, suppose your model is $Y_i = \beta_0 + x_i + e_i,$ where $e_i$ are
iid $Norm(0, \sigma_e).$ Also suppose that you have used the least squares
method to get estimates $\hat \beta_0$ of $\beta_0$ and $\hat \beta_1$ of 
$\beta_1.$ Then points on the least squares line are $(x_i, \hat Y_i),$ where
$\hat Y_i = \hat \beta_0 + \hat \beta_i x_i.$

As mentioned in the Comments, for this model, the best estimate of $\sigma_e^2$ is
$S_e^2 = \frac{\sum_i (Y_i - \hat Y_i)^2}{n-2}.$ This means that $S_e^2$ has the smallest the variance among unbiased estimators of $\sigma_e^2.$  Among
other advantages, this means that confidence and prediction intervals based
on $S_e^2$ are shorter than for other estimates of $\sigma_e^2$, and that
tests of hypothesis have the greatest power (other things being equal).

If the errors $e_i$ are not normal with constant variance $\sigma_e,$ then other estimates of variability about the regression line may give shorter CIs and
more powerful tests. In particular, an estimator based on $\sum_i |Y_i - \hat Y_i|$ has been used in some applications.